# If mysql input is empty echo default image else get picture in a table

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a little problem getting an image...

That is what I have:

```
<td data-label="Fotografija">
<?php
    if($row["fotografija"] == "") {
        echo '<img class="myImg" src="images/nislike.png" alt="Fotografija ni na voljo." style="max-width: 20%; min-width:100px;">';
    } else {
        echo '<img class="myImg" src="templates/slike/fotografije/?><?php 
        echo $row["fotografija"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row["ime"];?> <?php 
        echo $row["priimek"]; ?>" style="max-width: 20%; min-width:100px;">';
    }?>
</td>
```

The result is not working like it should.

I am getting the default picture (`images/nislike.png`) like expected but if there is an entry in mysql, it's not working.

Comment: We'll need more code to understand this

Comment: Try it with [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), so `if(!empty($row['fotografija'])){ // rest of code`.

Comment: But of course, that's all I can do without [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: try using `var_dump($row)`

Comment: tryed but not working. with the code i have i get the image if mysql table like expected but if there is an entry i get this:

 " alt=" " style="max-width: 20%; min-width:100px;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check that is `$row` have array or its empty.

```
var_dump($row);
```

Check, it should have some value or empty for `fotografija`

```
    <td data-label="Fotografija">
    <?php if($row["fotografija"] == "") { ?>
        <img class="myImg" src="images/nislike.png" alt="Fotografija ni na voljo." style="max-width: 20%; min-width:100px;">
    <?php } else { ?>
            <img class="myImg" src="templates/slike/fotografije/<?php echo $row["fotografija"]?>" alt="<?php echo $row["ime"].$row["priimek"]; ?>" style="max-width: 20%; min-width:100px;">
    <?php } ?>
    </td>
```

Comment: Answer accepted but my reputation is too low since iam new and my vote is not displayed publicly. Thanks again. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Remove ?> in this part:
`templates/slike/fotografije/<?php echo $row["fotografija"];`